# Flutter switch toggles off on its own

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I have created a flutter starter kit that allowes me to switch between themes in-app.

Now this works great but there is a small issue.

I have placed the switch button in the settings screen, 
but when I go to another screen and then back to the settings screen 
- it would seem that the switch button goes to Off mode on its own.

I'm attaching an image and [my code on github](https://github.com/JaserJsk/flutter_playground/tree/master/gambit_app) so that you guys can see what I mean.

[image]

```
class ThemeSwitchState extends State {
  bool switchControl = false;

  Future<bool> darkMode() async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return sharedPreferences.getBool("isDark");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<bool>(
      future: darkMode(),
      builder: (context, _snapshot) {
        return Transform.scale(
          scale: 1.5,
          child: Switch(
            value: _snapshot.data ?? false,
            onChanged: (value) {
              save(value);
              setState(() {

              });
            },
            activeColor: CustomColors().duskBlue,
            activeTrackColor: CustomColors().noroGrey,
            inactiveThumbColor: CustomColors().lureGrey,
            inactiveTrackColor: CustomColors().noroGrey,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  void save(bool value) async{
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await sharedPreferences.setBool("isDark", value);
  }

  void toggleSwitch(bool value) {
    ThemeChanger _themeChanger =
        Provider.of<ThemeChanger>(context, listen: false);

    if (switchControl == false) {
      setState(() {
        switchControl = true;
      });
      print('Theme is Dark');

      _themeChanger.setTheme(CustomThemes.darkTheme.copyWith(
          textTheme:
              CustomThemes.darkTextTheme(CustomThemes.darkTheme.textTheme)));
    } else {
      setState(() {
        switchControl = false;
      });
      print('Theme is Light');

      _themeChanger.setTheme(CustomThemes.lightTheme.copyWith(
          textTheme:
              CustomThemes.lightTextTheme(CustomThemes.lightTheme.textTheme)));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **SharedPreferences** from https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences
to save the last value of the **CheckBox**

I wrote an example

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class Settings extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SettingsState createState() => _SettingsState();
}

class _SettingsState extends State<Settings> {

  Future<bool> darkMode() async{
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return sharedPreferences.getBool("isNight");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("Night Mode"),
            FutureBuilder<bool>(
              future: darkMode(),
              builder: (context, _snapshot){
                return Checkbox(
                  value: _snapshot.data ?? false,
                  onChanged: (value){
                    save(value);
                    setState(() {
                       toggleSwitch(value);
                    });
                  },
                );
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


  void save(bool value) async{
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await sharedPreferences.setBool("isNight", value);
  }
}
```

**EDIT: WITH SWITCH**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class Settings extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SettingsState createState() => _SettingsState();
}

class _SettingsState extends State<Settings> {

  Future<bool> darkMode() async{
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return sharedPreferences.getBool("isNight");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("Night Mode"),
            FutureBuilder<bool>(
              future: darkMode(),
              builder: (context, _snapshot){
                return Switch(
                  value: _snapshot.data ?? false,
                  onChanged: (value){
                    save(value);
                    setState(() {

                    });
                  },
                );
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


  void save(bool value) async{
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await sharedPreferences.setBool("isNight", value);
  }
}
```

**UPDATE** *use value instead of switchControl*

```
  void toggleSwitch(bool value) {
    ThemeChanger _themeChanger =
        Provider.of<ThemeChanger>(context, listen: false);

    if (value) {
      setState(() {
        switchControl = true;
      });
      print('Theme is Dark');

      _themeChanger.setTheme(CustomThemes.darkTheme.copyWith(
          textTheme:
              CustomThemes.darkTextTheme(CustomThemes.darkTheme.textTheme)));
    } else {
      setState(() {
        switchControl = false;
      });
      print('Theme is Light');

      _themeChanger.setTheme(CustomThemes.lightTheme.copyWith(
          textTheme:
              CustomThemes.lightTextTheme(CustomThemes.lightTheme.textTheme)));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not working with my switch, I did as you said but still

Comment: Use a CheckBox then...Like I did

Comment: I was hoping to use a switch as I like that more. - I have added my current code, please take alook at it. What Am I supposed to write in the setState block ?

Comment: Oh, you don't have to put anything there...It is kept there so anytime the switch is changed the UI is rebuilt with the new value...If you remove it as it were....You'd notice the UI doesn't get updated

Comment: Yeah so far it is working as I'm able to save the state of the switch - however now I can not get it to switch any theme. 

somehow I need to call the` toggleSwitch` function in the switch value field but it is not working

Comment: I've updated it.. call toggleSwitch() in the setState

Comment: The theme is now switching however the issue is that - the switch state is not in sync with the current theme selected.

So sometimes the `off mode = light theme` and somethimes `on mode is dark theme`

Comment: Nevermind I got it to work, Thank you for your help!